# Jest with Create React App: Test suite failed to run - Unexpected token

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app, yarnpkg

Out of the box create-react-app with jest is always failing

Steps I did

```
create-react-app cra-test
cd cra-test
yarn install
```

Changed the original `test` in `package.json` into this

```
{
  "name": "cra-test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "jest",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

When I run `yarn test` the test failed. Here's the output

```
yarn run v1.1.0
$ jest
FAIL  src\App.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    .../cra-test/src/App.test.js: Unexpected token (7:18)
         5 | it('renders without crashing', () => {
         6 |   const div = document.createElement('div');
      >  7 |   ReactDOM.render(<App />, div);
           |                   ^
         8 |   ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
         9 | });
        10 |

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.413s, estimated 12s
Ran all test suites.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I have read that this might be caused by upgrading Jest that it become incompatible with create-react-app, but I did not do such thing.

```
node --version && yarn --version && npm --version && create-react-app --version
v6.10.2
1.1.0
5.7.1
1.4.3
```

Comment: why change the original test?

Comment: I agree with @VivekN, simply creating the app, running the test script works 100%. It's also using Jest to test. I'm confused as to what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you eject create-react-app, you have neither babel config nor jest config in your root dir, hence jest doesn't know it has to transpile sources. So you have to create .babelrc:

```
{
 "presets": [
   "react-app"
  ]
}
```

and jest.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  "collectCoverageFrom": [
    "src/**/*.{js,jsx,mjs}"
  ],
  "setupFiles": [
    "<rootDir>/config/polyfills.js"
  ],
  "testMatch": [
    "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,mjs}",
    "<rootDir>/src/**/?(*.)(spec|test).{js,jsx,mjs}"
  ],
  "testEnvironment": "node",
  "testURL": "http://localhost",
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
    "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
    "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|mjs|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
  },
  "transformIgnorePatterns": [
    "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$"
  ],
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "^react-native$": "react-native-web"
  },
  "moduleFileExtensions": [
    "web.js",
    "mjs",
    "js",
    "json",
    "web.jsx",
    "jsx",
    "node"
  ]
}
```

*These configs you can find after you do npm run eject.*

`babel-preset-react-app` should be installed since jest config refers to it. Also, note that jest config mentions `config` directory which is a part of create-react-app. Which means it's not going to work without it, so you need to copy that dir from create-react-app or write your own setup files.

Comment: i think this is not the reason. Jest docs talks as it works with create-react-app configurations.

https://jestjs.io/docs/es-ES/tutorial-react

Comment: This is what fixed to me : 
    `npm i -D --exact jest-watch-typeahead@0.6.5`  


Refer to this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70204039/failed-to-initialize-watch-plugin-node-modules-jest-watch-typeahead-filename-js

Answer (score 1):

Test Suites: 0 of 1 total
FAIL  src/App.test.js
× renders learn react link (6ms)

● renders learn react link

```
ReferenceError: React is not defined

  3 |
  4 | test('renders learn react link', () => { 
> 5 |   render(<App />);
    |          ^
  6 |   const linkElement = screen.getByText(/learn react/i);
  7 |   expect(linkElement).toBeInTheDocument();
  8 | });

  at Object.<anonymous> (src/App.test.js:5:10)
```

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        6.378s, estimated 17s
Ran all test suites.
Determining test suites to run...
--watch is not supported without git/hg, please use --watchAll

Answer (score -1):

I do not know the cause, but I fixed it for the moment below.
`export CI=1`
[Bibliography](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=f_RZDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA49&lpg=PA49&dq=src/App.test.js:+Unexpected+token+(7:18)&source=bl&ots=wdXBr8MXOb&sig=GsIYSjzHlxV8yTnyiQk8_HcYAzc&hl=ja&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwizz7PFqNLbAhVDX5QKHYAnD_sQ6AEIYDAG#v=onepage&q=src%2FApp.test.js%3A%20Unexpected%20token%20(7%3A18)&f=false)