# create react app tests not running without any changes to the code

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I ran create-react-app.

Made no changes and ran the tests.

The tests failed straight away.

Error: Failed to initialize watch plugin "node_modules/jest-watch-typeahead/filename.js":

● Test suite failed to run

```
file:///C:/_Projects/my-app/node_modules/jest-watch-typeahead/build/file_name_plugin/prompt.js:4
import { PatternPrompt, printPatternCaret, printRestoredPatternCaret } from 'jest-watcher';
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: The requested module 'jest-watcher' is expected to be of type CommonJS, which does not support named exports. CommonJS modules can be imported by importing the default export.
For example:
import pkg from 'jest-watcher';
const { PatternPrompt, printPatternCaret, printRestoredPatternCaret } = pkg;

  at async requireOrImportModule (node_modules/jest-util/build/requireOrImportModule.js:65:32)
  at async watch (node_modules/@jest/core/build/watch.js:337:34)
  at async _run10000 (node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.js:311:7)
```

What the deuce?

Can anyone please help?

Comment: There is an issue open for this same bug on github. You can try some of the solutions suggested by folks there https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11792

Comment: Also found similar question on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70204039/failed-to-initialize-watch-plugin-node-modules-jest-watch-typeahead-filename-js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known issue and is related to the version of node you are using. Check out https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11792.

Resolve it by upgrading to the latest node version >16. This worked for me. https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Comment: My question would be: why it is failing now if he has been running the same version of everything and they worked before? Maybe the versioning in his package.json is a range and not a single version, but I'm experiencing myself issues like this and all my versions are single versions, and I'm running crazy trying to guess why now my tests won't just run.